# LINQ Flatten Circular Reference

Tags: c#, linq

I have a user object:

```
class user
{
  int userId {get; set;}
  string name {get; set}
  int supervisorId {get; set}
}
```

Each supervisorId is also a useId in the users table.  I'm trying to find a reasonable way to build out a hierarchy of a user's supervisors, all the way to the top person.  So selecting a user's supervisorID, then that supervisor's supervisorId, etc.  I'm working with an ever more ugly growing for loop now but hoping someone has something a little more elegant.

Comment: Please show your "inelegant"  code (and not everything has an elegant solution in all languages).

Comment: There's no question here, only a list of things you want. What's your question? And what does the title "linq flatten circular reference" have to do with your problem?  The body text nowhere mentions linq, flattening, or circular references.

Comment: What is the supervisor ID of a person with no supervisor?

Comment: The CEO, and I have code in place to stop at that level.

Comment: I don’t know what “build out a hierarchy” means in this context. You already have a hierarchy. My guess is you need an algorithm to *walk* the hierarchy to obtain a specific result or result set. What output do you need?

Comment: The question is not clear as others have pointed out but I'm going to try anyway... So you mention a user table. Is this actually LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework optimisation problem? If you want to avoid fetching the whole table and avoid making X different queries for a single UserId, you should look into using a view with a recursive CTE to build the hierarchy on the SQL side, then query that view with LINQ  to get all (and only) the data you need in a single query.

Comment: We actually had a stored procedure building the CTE on the SQL side but we're trying to get rid of all of our stored procedures and do everything in LINQ.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need a stored procedure to build a CTE, you can juste write a VIEW that uses a CTE and query that view with LINQ like you would query a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by making your user object less horrible:

```
class User
{
  public int Id {get; private set;}
  public string Name {get; private set;}
  private int supervisorId;
  public User Supervisor 
  {
    get { ... implement it ... } 
  }
```

Have `Supervisor` return `null` for a user with no supervisor.

Now you can implement:

```
  public IEnumerable<User> ManagementChain()
  {
    User current = this.Supervisor;
    while(current != null) 
    {
      yield return current;
      current = current.Supervisor;
    }
  }
}
```

And you're done; you now have a sequence of supervisors for any user. The top-most user has an empty sequence of supervisors.

Comment: Our model is already set up like that and, now, I'm populating the Supervisor child object.  I'm trying to implement the ManagementChain method but it's only bringing back the first supervisor.  Should I be using ManagementChain on the user object, or in the service where I populate the user object?

Answer (score 1):

Going based off of the class in your original post, I put together a little example of how to use a recursive method in order to travel up the List (or whatever enumerable you had) of users until it found the supervisor.   I did assume that the supervisors at the top had a set supervisor id to identify them as top level.  I put 0 in there for now for the sake of being able to show this.

There are 2 examples, one that returns the supervisor only, and one that returns the entire hierarchy.

```
public class Program  {

private const int SupervisorId = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  List<user> users = new List<user>();
  users.Add(new user {userId = 1, name = "1", supervisorId = SupervisorId});
  users.Add(new user { userId = 2, name = "2", supervisorId = SupervisorId});
  users.Add(new user { userId = 3, name = "3", supervisorId = 1 });
  users.Add(new user { userId = 4, name = "4", supervisorId = 1 });
  users.Add(new user { userId = 5, name = "5", supervisorId = 2 });
  users.Add(new user { userId = 6, name = "6", supervisorId = 5 });

  var nonSupervisors = users.Where(u => u.supervisorId != SupervisorId);
  Dictionary<user, user> userAndSupervisor = nonSupervisors.ToDictionary(user => user, user => FindSupervisor(users, user));
  Dictionary<user, List<user>> userAndHierarchy =nonSupervisors.ToDictionary(user => user, user => FindSupervisorHierarchy(users, user));
}

static user FindSupervisor(List<user> users, user user)
{
  var parentUser = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userId == user.supervisorId);
  if (parentUser?.supervisorId != SupervisorId)
  {
    parentUser = FindSupervisor(users, parentUser);
  }
  return parentUser;
}

static List<user> FindSupervisorHierarchy(List<user> users, user user)
{
  var parentUsers = users.Where(u => u.userId == user.supervisorId);
  if (parentUsers.All(x => x.supervisorId != SupervisorId))
  {
    parentUsers = parentUsers.Concat(FindSupervisorHierarchy(users, parentUsers.FirstOrDefault()));
  }
  return parentUsers.ToList();
}
}
```

Comment: This gets me really close.  I actually only need to build the hierarchy based off one person.  So based on a user, then their boss, then their boss.  Think I can get that from this.  Thank you!

Comment: The "FindSupervisorHierarchy" method should do this for you then.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to find a way to determine if a specific user is the top person? Wouldn't an empty SupervisorId indicate that?

You could make SupervisorId nullable

```
int? supervisorId
```

and

```
while(supervisorId != null)
{
    //Check supervisor's supervisorId
}
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a hierarchy of supervisors.  So I pass in a userId, get their supervisor, then that supervisor's supervisor, etc.

Comment: So why not using this loop, add the ids to a `List<int>` and be done with it?